# HTML tags showing in my profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Selecting that I'm interested in both "Full time permanent" and "Temporary contract" like this:

---

[image: Selecting these checkboxes]

---

results in some `<span>` tags being escaped and rendered:

---

[image: Bug]

---

The source looks like this:

```
<span>full-time position&lt;/span&gt; or &lt;span&gt;contract</span>.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We’ve fixed this, thank you for the heads-up.