# There's <p> all over my profile. :(

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML tags showing in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125433/html-tags-showing-in-my-profile)

Something funny must be going on with the latest patch, I have a bunch of `<p>` tags encoded to regular text such that I visually see rendered as:

```
<p>I was lucky enough to have a computer....
```

The page serves this:

```
&lt;p&gt;I was lucky enough to have a computer
```

Some encoding issues I would guess.

Comment: `<p>` is that new new stuff.  All the kids are using it.

Comment: This was reported and *apparently* [resolved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125433/html-tags-showing-in-my-profile)...

Comment: .........gross.

Comment: As long as there's no `<p>` in the connection pool, we're okay.

Comment: I really should switch the other to be a dupe of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed. We tightened the vice on some encoding stuff. Thanks for the heads-up.